# Why does an absolutely positioned child of a statically position parent takes the full width of the viewport?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been learning to make a basic drop-down from [this w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text). It is said that we can change the width of drop-down content by setting `min-width` to 100%. It works very well. But if I change the `position: relative` to `position: static` the drop-down content eventually takes 100% width of the window. AFAIK `width: 100%` should set the width to 100% of the parent container. Changing the postion of parent container to static doesn't change it's width so the child should not spread across the parent container. Following is the code I am trying:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> - So, why is setting `position-static` for `.dropdown` class(or parent element in general) causing the `.dropdown-content` class elements(or child elements in general) to have full screen width rather than having same width as that of the parent container?

**Addendum:** It seems that an absolutely positioned child of a statically position parent takes the full width of the viewport. E.g. the following code:

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#one{border: 2px dotted red; position: static; width:100px;}

div#two{border: 2px solid blue; width:100%; position: absolute;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">

Text of statically positioned box
<div id="two"> Text of absolutely positioned box.</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The blue box is spread across the whole viewport and is outside the parent container which has a red border. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

`Static` is the default behaviour of any element on page. So when you make `.dropdown-content`'s position as `absolute`, it sets its width according to the **nearest relatively positioned parent**, which in your case is the viewport as no other element is relatively positioned.

But the movement you position the `.dropdown` as relative, and `.dropdown-content` as absolute, `.dropdown-content`(which is a child of `.dropdown`) gets it width from the nearest **relatively positioned** parent(`.dropdown`), and this is the reason why the `.dropdown-content` is taking full width when it's parent(`.dropdown`) is statically positioned .

```css
.dropdown {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.dropdownRelative {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent{
 position: relative;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,.dropdownRelative:hover .dropdown-content,.parent:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>I am statically positioned and parent as static.</p>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="dropdownRelative">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>I am absolutely positioned and my parent is relatively positioned</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>Hover over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">My parent is relatively positioned!</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_it sets its width according to the nearest **relative** element,_" -- relative or parent?

Comment: Nearest relative parent. I have edited the sentence now.

Comment: I think you mean _nearest parent container_

Comment: You can call it as nearest relatively positioned parent/container, both are the same.

Comment: "_...which in your case is the **viewport** as no other element is relatively positioned._" Isn't the nearest, or the only, parent container div having class `.dropdown`?

Comment: In your case as `.drodown` is having position as **static**, so it behaves normally. Therefore `.dropdown` is not the **nearest relatively positioned parent** of `.dropdown-content`, it's actually the body tag which is taking the complete width of the viewport.

Comment: If that was so then the red border wouldn't be around _mouse over me_ text; it would be around the whole viewport. Edit: Could you also give any reference which claim that setting `postion:static` removes the parent?

Comment: You have given the red border on the parent, and the child, therefore it's only around the text.

Comment: If setting `position: static` removes the **nearest relatively positioned parent** then the dropdown-content should not inherit properties from the dropdown parent but it still inherits properties like `color`.

Comment: Please see the demo once, I have added 3 examples in that, you can see that whenever parent is `relative`, and child is `absolute`, the child takes parent's width.

Comment: Position only affects in terms of positioning related properties and not other properties as you can see in w3schools "absolute The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element". Its only in terms of positioning.

Comment: Consider this code. Position:static doesn't remove the parent div's positioning properies: <DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#one{border: 2px dotted red; position: static; width:100px;}

div#two{border: 2px solid blue; width:50%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">

Text TExt
<div id="two"> text2 text2</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Yes, it doesn't remove parent div's properties. static is the default property of any element on page. Had `.one`'s position been relative and `.two`'s position absolute it would have affected '.two`'s positioning on the page.  You can refer [this](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) page.

Comment: The link you have given is interesting. It says, "_it limits the scope of absolutely positioned child elements..._" But unfortunately the link to details is broken. I want to know why an absolute positioned child of a relative position parent takes the full width of the viewport.

Comment: Absolute positioned child of a relative position parent does not take full width.

Comment: Sorry the other way round. Absolutely positioned child of a statically position parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103010/discussion-between-sahil-and-user31782).